# Can't open database in MVC project Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have an MVC project. When I added database I couldn't open it or create new tables. (I added it with right click on "App_Data" -> Add new Item -> SQL Server DB)

[Right click on my DB and there is no option for creating tables or something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OVK1.png)
[image: Right click on my DB and there is no option for creating tables or something]

[When I open DB with double click there are strange symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSDoS.png)
[image: When I open DB with double click there are strange symbols]

In Server Explorer my DB is absent

How can I work with my DB?

Comment: did you check your connection?

Comment: Open sql server management and check your connection to de db.

Comment: How to check the connection? How to open sql server management?

Comment: Those aren't "strange symbols"; that's the binary content of the .mdf file.

Comment: You need to connect to the database, using the Server Explorer window.

Comment: How? In "Open with" programs there is no appropriate one. And in the Server Explorer I couldn't add the connection. In videos about creation DB after adding the DB in Server Explorer this DB are added automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the .mdf file from Data Connections section in the Server Explorer, 
Right click on 'Data Connections' section on the Server Explorer and select 'Add Connection...' and select 'Microsoft SQL Server Database File' and browse your solution .mdf file.

[image: Screenshot]